# Categories of Bioacoustics Software

Tags: methods, software

Some of you may have seen Tessa Rhinehart great list of bioacoustics software https://github.com/rhine3/bioacoustics-software

We're in the process of trying to turn this into an easier to use searchable database that will live in a github repo.

We want to establish the different kinds of areas within bioacoustics research that software tools address. There may be no standard pipeline to a bioacoustics research project - but maybe we can agree to a schema that best categorizes what software bioacousticians use. Packages might span multiple categories.

Our current list:

- Data exploration
- Organization and annotation
- Sound processing
- Acoustic parameter measurement
- Localization
- Detection
- Classification

What do others think?

Comment: There could be a better repo than GitHub (Microsoft)? If we want an "easier to use searchable database", then maybe GitHub is not the best. If I find a good one, then I would post it in an answer. I sure would like to see what the community proposes.

Comment: @sm1 I like Wikidata for this kind of information - essentially, it's a more serious version of "wikipedia lists". But wikidata is not always the easiest to use. On the other hand, Github is not a bad choice, because it's very easy to extract the data out (because of the use of git and markdown), so there's no Microsoft commitment involved.

Comment: @Dan Stowell I recommend avoiding GitHub because it's owned by Microsoft and the megalith seems to use the info in there for it's own benefits. See what they did with the code Copilot tool. They seem to disregard the copyright. And why not the wiki option for this community on stack exchange and which was mentioned in another answer here?

Answer (score 15):

Great initiative. I would also suggest...

- Open source
- Terrestrial and/or marine
- Data exploration *and visualization*
- High frequency compatible (i.e. can handle recordings around 384 - 576kHz sample rates)

Comment: Maybe split data exploration into data retrieval and data visualization instead? I took exploration as 'handling searching through and retrieving files for download' but 'presenting data visually for exploration' is equally valid

Answer (score 9):

This is great.  A soundscape characterization category could be useful.

Answer (score 8):

This is a great question, and like all good questions may not have an easy answer. Some important parameters in addition to those listed by other answers are clearly:

- Real time processing
- Offline processing
- Max channels
- Max sample rate (covered above)

Probably also good to list key species groups it's used for to date (though not trying to put people off using software e.g. developed to detect birds to detect marine mammals).

It may also be good to have some kind of compatibility table, i.e. can output from software A be used with software B?

Answer (score 7):

How about a community wiki for this info? It would be owned and managed by this community and hosted on this platform.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Comment: Great Idea--  We have had a discussion on the bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com site about wikis and agreed to temporarily pause on wiki until we shift to a public beta. We highly encourage more users to join discussions on META to help us run the site!!!  (see https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54/how-to-decide-when-a-topic-question-should-be-made-into-a-community-wiki)

Comment: Yes Shannon. I agree with the pause on the wiki. I'm still learning the ropes on this platform. I sure would like to avoid GitHub, though.

Comment: Happy to have you on board, your answer was a great excuse for me to encourage users to participate in our meta site- link always at the top of this site (see what I just did there). ;)